# add a second email address to a script

Tags: php, email

i have a script that i have modified to meet my requirements however i now need to send the email to more than one person, could someone point me in the right direction as to how i could modify the script to send to more than one person.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "emailremoved@sample.com";
    $email_subject = "Kro Catering Website Enquiry";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['your_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['type']) ||
        !isset($_POST['guests']) ||
        !isset($_POST['date']) ||
        !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $your_name = $_POST['your_name']; // required
    $type = $_POST['type']; // required
    $guests = $_POST['guests']; // required
    $date = $_POST['date']; // not required
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Your Name: ".clean_string($your_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Type: ".clean_string($type)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Guests: ".clean_string($guests)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Date: ".clean_string($date)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

<?php

   header( 'Location: /thanks.aspx' ) ;

?>

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for the line:

```
$email_to = "emailremoved@sample.com";
```

And keep adding e-mails with a comma separating them:

```
$email_to = "emailremoved@sample.com,emailremoved@sample.com,emailremoved@sample.com";
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP's `mail()` function is quite versatile when it comes to the "to" field.  [See the documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).  Any one of the listed examples would be fine:

```
user@example.com
user@example.com, anotheruser@example.com
User <user@example.com>
User <user@example.com>, Another User <anotheruser@example.com>
```

So since your `$email_to` variable is not cleaned or otherwise modified after you set it on line 5, you should be able to just put 2 there separated by a comma (as in the examples above that I copied from the documentation I linked to.)

Comment: Once again burned by taking the extra minute to look up the actual documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Try this!
It was the only code that worked for me.

```
$header .= 'Bcc: someaddress@email.com';
```